# How to connect epson printer to android device via wireless connection

Tags: android, printing, epson

Hi i am developing an app which connects to epson printer through wireless network and print receipts.Both My android phone and printer(TM-T88V-DT) is connected to same wireless network but my app not able to connect with my printer.I've setup printer and wireless connection as given in epson technical document and i am using sample provided along with epson epos sdk for android for testing,But sample app is not connecting with printer.I don't know what is going wrong with my setup Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Please share some code or reference to your repo so that I can look where you getting wrong. and please share a link which sample you taking as a reference.

I suggest you download the Android SDK and check the ePOS2_Printer sample given in the android sample. I am also working on the same my app is working fine and i am still learning that